# Do you know how to become Navteq (Here Maps) reseller?

Tags: address, nokia, here-maps

Before we begin, I'd like to state that I know that Navteq has been acquired by Nokia and Nokia has been acquired by Microsoft. However, Navteq was out of the deal. When I go through pages of Here Maps (old Navteq), I cannot find any information regarding the distribution of raw data other than APIs.

However, on the other hand, there are plenty of companies that claims to be Navteq data provider and they are able to provide sample datasets and license those datasets for commercial usage. As Nokia removed all pages related to Navteq and redirected the visitors to here.com I wonder if someone knows how to become Here Maps Premium Reseller?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business development

Comment: You are right Jason, however on the other hand It's probably the only place I can have an answer. So, I'll leave it to moderation.

Comment: Nokia Mapping is not part of the Microsoft purchase only the phone division is now Microsoft.

Comment: Mapperz, you are right. I also stated it in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

They have semi-rebranded but you could try to contact them directly at the link below.

http://here.com/abouthere/contactus/?lang=en-US

If that does not work, you may have to try to contact Nokia directly. Supposedly, Nokia held on to Navteq/HERE after selling assets to Microsoft.

Comment: Contact-us form didn't help, I originally tried to contact them  6 weeks prior to this post. I'd really appreciate some insight if anybody here is working for a company which is Navteq provider.